# Probability of winning at least $M$ games out of $N$

Tags: probability, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

In a ($2$ Player)game there are $2$ moves: $A,B$. The game is played $N$ times. The probability of choosing them is equal i.e. $0.5$ What is the probability that game will be won at least $M$ times by first player given first player moves first ?

I found out the condition of winning of each player without taking into account the probability of choosing the moves.

How can I think of the solution? What more do I need to calculate to find the probability. Can I calculate the probability in terms of given variables only?

Comment: What is the condition of victory?

Comment: @Wolfram The victory is based on nim game. Lets say the condition is if $X$ is even then it's a victory for first player else second player wins.

Comment: What is $X$? What do moves $A$ and $B$ do? I just don't understand the nature of the game, do you mean that $A$ or $B$ are the moves that players do independently one time in a game?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are two different set of moves. A player can choose either $A$ or $B$. Now I created a variable $X$ which tells me whether first player wins or second which is independent of set of moves.